# Get Data out of OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-adapter

I'm trying to get data out of the function OnClickListener from this spinner in Android Studio.
Here's a piece of the code.

```
roleAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.role, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
roleAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
roleSpinner.setAdapter(roleAdapter);

roleSpinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

@Override

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int ?>position, 
long id) {
String roleText = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();       
}
});
```

I have a "Next Button" to continue to the next Activity, but I want to check to make sure the user has selected an item from this spinner before proceeding to the next Activity, otherwise create a Toast message saying please select an item from this spinner.

Or maybe I just don't need to use an adapter... I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spinner has the method called spinner.getSelectedItem() to get the selected item of the spinner. By using that method, you can check whether a spinner item is selected or not as described in below code.

```
if(spinner != null && spinner.getSelectedItem() !=null ) {
    //one of the spinner items is selected. Do whatever you want.
} else  { 

}
```

Comment: Is this "getSelectedItem() and actually object?  Like could I pass it to another function?

Comment: yeah getSelectedItem() returns an object. it can be casted to String if you want.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this:

use `setOnitemSelectedListener` instead of `setOnItemClickListener`

```
 roleSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

           String roleText = String.valueOf(roleSpinner.getSelectedItem());
        }
```

Comment: Yeah, tried that.  Still couldn't test it against the state of the spinner.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a class member variable in your Activity like this

```
private String roleText;
```

Then in your `onItemSelectedListener` set that variable to whatever the user selects

```
roleSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       roleText = String.valueOf(roleSpinner.getSelectedItem());
    }
};
```

then when they click the "Next Button" you can check whether the variable has been set

```
if( roleText != null ) {
    // Toast message saying they have to select something
}
else {
    // go to next activity
}
```

Comment: Rather than checking if the string is empty (you should also check for null), I would disable the button until the adapter item is selected (or do both)

Comment: Good points. I'll keep it as is since the OP specifically asked about showing a toast, but disabling it may be better UX (as long as the user isn't left confused about why the button is disabled).